# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual ....your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')........ at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute this query with a huge query 
and this is my db query................................

```
 CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`govtracker` ( `id` DOUBLE(10000) NOT NULL , 
 `site_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `region` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
 `site_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `site_code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
 `tac_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `dt_readiness` DATE NOT NULL , `rfs` 
 BOOLEAN NOT NULL , `rfs_date` DATE NOT NULL , 
 `huawei_1st_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL , `te_1st_submission_date` 
 DATE NOT NULL , `huawei_2nd_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL , 
 `te_2nd_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL , `huawei_3rd_submission_date` 
 DATE NOT NULL , `te_3rd_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL , 
 `acceptance_date_opt` DATE NOT NULL , `acceptance_date_plan` DATE NOT 
 NULL , `signed_sites` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `as_built_date` DATE NOT 
 NULL , `as_built_status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `date_dt` DATE NOT NULL 
 , `dt_status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `shr_status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
 , `dt_planned` INT(1000) NOT NULL , `integeration_status` VARCHAR(255) 
 NOT NULL , `comments_snags` LONGTEXT NOT NULL , `cluster_name` LONGTEXT 
 NOT NULL , `type_standalone_colocated` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
 `installed_type_standalone_colocated` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `status` 
 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `pending` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
 `pending_status` LONGTEXT NOT NULL , `problematic_details` LONGTEXT NOT 
 NULL , `ets_tac` INT(100000) NOT NULL , `region_r` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
 , `sf6_signed_date` DATE NOT NULL , `sf6_signed_comment` LONGTEXT NOT 
 NULL , `comment_history` LONGTEXT NOT NULL , `on_air_owner` VARCHAR(255) 
 NOT NULL , `pp_owner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `report_comment` LONGTEXT 
 NOT NULL , `hu_opt_area_owner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `planning_owner` 
 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `po_number` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
 `trigger_date` DATE NOT NULL , `as_built_status_tr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

but I find this sql error

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
 near ') NOT NULL , `site_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `region` 
 VARCHAR(255) NOT NUL' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `DOUBLE(10000)` supposed to be?

You can just use `DOUBLE`.  However, making an `id` a double is highly not recommended.  I would instead recommend:

```
id int auto_increment primary key,
```

or, if you think that `int` isn't big enough, use `bigint`.

Comment: It supposing that id is auto increment primary key

Answer (score 2):

`DOUBLE()` takes two parameters, `M` and `D`, where `M` is the total number of digits and `D` is the number of digits following the decimal point. Max value for `M` is 255.

You also have some `INT(1000)` values, where `INT()` has a max value of 255.

This is the correct query, assuming we set the `DOUBLE()` and `INT()` values to their max of 255:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`govtracker` (
    `id` DOUBLE(255, 0) NOT NULL,
    `site_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `region` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `site_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `site_code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `tac_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `dt_readiness` DATE NOT NULL,
    `rfs` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    `rfs_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `huawei_1st_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `te_1st_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `huawei_2nd_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `te_2nd_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `huawei_3rd_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `te_3rd_submission_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `acceptance_date_opt` DATE NOT NULL,
    `acceptance_date_plan` DATE NOT NULL,
    `signed_sites` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `as_built_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `as_built_status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `date_dt` DATE NOT NULL,
    `dt_status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `shr_status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `dt_planned` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `integeration_status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `comments_snags` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `cluster_name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `type_standalone_colocated` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `installed_type_standalone_colocated` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `pending` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `pending_status` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `problematic_details` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `ets_tac` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `region_r` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `sf6_signed_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `sf6_signed_comment` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `comment_history` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `on_air_owner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `pp_owner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `report_comment` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `hu_opt_area_owner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `planning_owner` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `po_number` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `trigger_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `as_built_status_tr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Tip for the next time, try to format your query because this was a pain to clean up. Another pro tip, services like https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/ make it really easy to debug syntax like this.